# Como posso atribuir valor de uma variável php a um input com JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

Estou tentando jogar um valor resgatado pelo `php` e jogar em um `input` com `JQuery` e em seguida efetuar um submit em um determinado formulário, o que tentei fazer é isso aqui:

```
if (!empty($_POST['Termo'])) {

    $Termo = $_POST['Termo'];

    echo "
    
    jQuery(function($) {
        document.querySelector('[name='Termo']').value = '" . $Termo . "';  
        document.forms['frmBusca'].submit();
    }); 
    

    ";  

}
```

O input tem o nome de `Termo` mas não acontece nada, ao receber a variável `Termo` verifico e ela tem conteúdo.

Comment: Porque tem um ternário dentro do `if`?

Comment: Porque não fazes echo dentro do HTML do input? em vez de estar a setar com JavaScript um elemento que é gerado no PHP também

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@adventistapr**, Um comando echo é meio chato de php. Tente diferente e segue abaixo:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Termo'])) {
    $Termo = $_POST['Termo'];
?>
jQuery(function($) {
        document.querySelector('[name='Termo']').value = '" . $Termo . "';  
        document.forms['frmBusca'].submit();
});
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: faltou o echo: 
document.querySelector('[name='Termo']').value = '<?php echo $Termo ?>';

Comment: Não precisa echo, e faça o seu teste xampp =)

Comment: Sem <php echo $var ?> o que vai ser impresso é exatamente o que está escrito: value = '" . $Termo . "'; 
 mas o que se quer é que fique assim:
value = 'abcdef'; sendo que $_POST['Termo'] = "abcdef"

Comment: Esse `$termo` vai gerar um erro de javascript... Tem de o produzir (fazer o print) do lado servidor, com php